# How can I draw a graph of adjacency matrix in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw this picture, but I can't
How can help me?[image]

Comment: I'm not able to help with the drawing right now, but you probably want to change "garph" to "graph" in your title.

Comment: You could start by looking, for example, at the `automata drawing library` of TikZ (section 43, p.571 of the current documentation (v3.1.10)).